# Authentication using an external service?

Tags: authentication, basic-authentication

I need to create a very static website so a heavy CMS and custom coding is a total overkill. Some areas need to be password-protected, however, which requires authentication. Can I use Google/Facebook or another service to authenticate users without me having to use a database and custom code myself?

**In other words, can I create just the static content and use an external service for authorizing access?**

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can with Google, check [Using OAuth 2.0 for Client-side Applications](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent).

Comment: José, would it be possible to do the same with PayPal? I.e. Can I authorize access for only those who have paid using the PayPal database with only client-side code?

Comment: No directly with PayPal if the site is 100% static. PayPal doesn't have this oauth flow today. I work for auth0.com(an auth broker) an with our service you can use this flow with PayPal and I think it will be possible to grant access only to paid users using out rules feature.

Comment: Btw this was not in your original question.

Comment: This sounds great. Would auth0.com allow for a zero-database solution? I want to use only PayPal's infrastructure to authenticate and verify paying members; I don't want to store user data myself.